# map_Kd missing from MTL file

Tags: texturing, materials, export, 3d-printing

I am trying to add colours to a cube and export them as an OBJ file for use with a 3d printing program.  When I do so, the MTL file is created, but the map_Kd file is not noted in the MTL and therefore the program cannot use the OBJ properly.

When looking at the object (a cube in this case) using both the texture and material display methods in Blender they both show the colours on each face.

The steps I have followed to create the uv mapping, then the material and texture are:

- Switch to Blender Cycles Render
- Entering edit mode, selecting all edges, marking the seams (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> menu), unwrapping it, and save the UV as a png.
- I edit the PNG using gimp/ms paint (simple colours)
- In Blender, go to the materials tab and click new
- The surface is set to diffuse BSDF, and I click on the *Color* option, and then select image texture.
- Click on *Open* and navigate to the folder with the png file and select it.
- Change the UV view to the nodes view, and in the main window choose to view the texture rather than solid, you can see the colours are now on the cube, and there is a new node containing the new material.
- I then select export obj and have the following options ticked:
  a) *Apply Modifiers* b) *Include Edges* c) *Write Normals* d) *Include UVs* e) *Write Materials* f) *Objects as OBJ objects* g) *Path Mode Auto*

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated, have I actually created the material using these steps?  And have I applied the texture correctly?

Comment: Sounds like you did a good with the material, but maybe try using Blender Internal render engine and materials instead. Might work better for OBJ export.

Comment: thanks for the reply, i need to be able to export the uv mapping, and unwrap the object, and that doesn't seem to work within blender render.  Do you know of a guide I can follow using blender render?

Comment: UV Maps are part of mesh data, and thus render engine independent, they are exported regardless of the active one. The OBJ exporter is older though, probably closer to Blender Internal age, I believe it will support texture export better for Internal materials. Also have this in mind https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

Comment: I face the same problem in 3DS max. The .mtl file references an obj file with map_Kd and as such i can't import it correctly, nor find this .bmp file.